# Jointly continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This is Exercise 2.7.20 from Probability and Random Processes by Grimmett and Stirzaker:

If $U$ and $V$ are jointly continuous, show that $P(U = V) = 0$.

Is this proof correct?

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Since $U$ and $V$ are jointly continuous the joint distribution function of $U$ and $V$ can be written as,

$$
P(U \leq x, V \leq y) = F(x, y) = \int_{-\infty}^y \int_{-\infty}^x f(u, v)\, du\,dv
$$

from some $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ which is integrable. $P(U = V)$ is then given by,

\begin{eqnarray}
P(U = V) = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^x f(u, v)\, du\,dv - \lim_{y' \rightarrow x} \lim_{x' \rightarrow x}\int_{-\infty}^{y'} \int_{-\infty}^{x'} f(u, v)\, du\,dv  = 0,
\end{eqnarray}

as required. $\square$

**EDIT (2015/09/22)**

Based on the comments below, I think this is the correct proof.

**Corrected Proof:**

Since $U$ and $V$ are jointly continuous the joint distribution function of $U$ and $V$ can be written as,

$$
P(U \leq x, V \leq y) = F(x, y) = \int_{-\infty}^y \int_{-\infty}^x f(u, v)\, du\,dv
$$

from some $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ which is integrable. $P(U = V)$ is then given by,

\begin{eqnarray}
P(U = V) = \int \!\!\! \int_{\{(u, v) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | u = v\}}  f(u, v)\, du\,dv = 0,
\end{eqnarray}

as required.$\square$

Comment: Note that aside from the problems mentioned in the answers, you can't assume that $(U, V)$ has a density. The distribution is just meant to be continuous, not absolutely continuous.

Comment: So does that mean that I can't assume that $F(x, y)$ can be written as,
$$
F(x, y) = \int_{-\infty}^y \int_{-\infty}^x f(u, v)\, du\,dv.
$$

Comment: when I googled 'jointly continuous', I did find some definitions that were of absolute continuity. So I guess it depends on the lecturer / how much measure theory they want you to know. @Raj, consult your text/notes and make sure you can assume it has a density.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. The book says that I can assume $F(x, y)$ can be written as above. I guess that in more advanced work, this assumption can be dropped?

Answer (score 4):

What you have is proof that: $\mathsf P(U=x, V=x)=0$

$\begin{align}
P(U =x, V=x) & = \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^x f(u, v)\operatorname du\operatorname dv - \lim_{t \rightarrow x} \lim_{s \rightarrow x}\int_{-\infty}^{t} \int_{-\infty}^{s} f(u, v)\operatorname du\operatorname dv \\[1ex] ~ & = 0
\end{align}$

Which is totally not what is required.

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. I need to integrate over the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $U = V$ instead of what I wrote above.

Comment: @Raj Moreover you need to establish that the integral over the entire support is almost surely zero.

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT: I misunderstood the question. move along, nothing to see here...)

Let $(U,V) = (x,x)$ on the probability space $[0,1]^2$. Then $U=V$ surely, but $P(U=x,V=x) = P(U=x) = 0$. We see that there is a difference between

$$ 0 = P(U=V) = P(ω :∃ x ,  U(ω)=V(ω)=x )$$

and

$$ ∀ x,\ 0 = P(U=V=x)$$

Comment: The definition of $(U,V)$ is unsound. Later on, $P(U=V)$ is not $P(ω : ∀ x,\ U(ω)=V(ω) =x )$ (which probably stands for $P(\{ω : ∀ x,\ U(ω)=V(ω) =x \})$).

Comment: Ah, I think by "$(U,V)$ is unsound" you mean they don't form a jointly continuous r.v., which is true. I'll just edit this in and leave my answer up for shame. Thanks @Did :)

Comment: No I was able to guess that you meant that (U,V) is almost surely on the diagonal, but the problem is that the formulation "Let $(U,V) = (x,x)$ on the probability space $[0,1]^2$." means nothing.

Comment: Sorry, don't follow. Why?

Comment: What is this $x$ when you invoke it in "Let $(U,V)=(x,x)$"?

Comment: Well whenever I see this abuse of notation I assume it means $x=\text{id}$. I normally catch these too, but I guess it takes a long time to recover from the high school favourite 'let $y=f(x)$' :) Sorry!

Comment: @did Actually, I relearned this notation when working with multivariate fourier stuff to keep track of the variables...So actually. In this case, if you have better notation to use, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: But $x$ is not the identity here hence the problem is not only notational. Your intent might have been to define $(U,V)$ on $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ by $U(x,y)=V(x,y)=x$ for every $(x,y)$ in $\Omega$. Then there are much simpler ways to do so and we should not have to scratch our heads on this...

Comment: A canonical version: "Let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and $V=U$". Notes: 1. Nearly always better to leave $\Omega$ unspecified. 2. Your post does not specify the distribution of $U$, which is a  pity since, if $U$ has atoms, the example fails.

Comment: Well no, it isn't the identity on $[0,1]^2$, $\text{id}_{[0,1]^2}$ wouldn't make $(x,x)$ take values in $[0,1]^2$, so it is implied that by $\text{id}$, I meant $\text{id}_{[0,1]}$. Your projection example is quite convincing but doesn't fit the way its normally abused, because it is implicit that $U,V$ only take one variable since $y$ (another copy of  $\text{id}_{[0,1]}$) makes no appearance. In any case, I do agree its not the best way to write things, and if it really bothers you I can change it. (Also I of course meant the uniform measure.)

Comment: Be assured that I am not the least *bothered* by the content of your answer.

Comment: Alright then, thanks for the discussion @Did :)

Comment: Useful discussion and comments, thanks!