# For two continuous RVs $X$ and $Y$ such that $Y=X$, does $P(X=Y)=1$ hold?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

> Given that there are two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $Y=X$. Does this mean that $P(X=Y)=1$?

My guess is that though $X$ and $Y$ are separately continuous, it is not mentioned that they are jointly continuous. So the joint density may not exist, in which case I cannot conclude that $P(X=Y)=1$. In other words, there does not exist any integrable function $f$ such that $P(X\le x,Y\le y)=\int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^y f(u,v)\,du\,dv$ unless both the RVs are jointly continuous. But whenever it is said that $X=Y$, isn't it understood as being true almost everywhere, i.e., with probability $1$?

So should I conclude that $P(X=Y)=0$ in any case?

This also leads me to ask if it is necessarily true that $P(X=Y)=\int\int_{\substack\{(u,v):u=v\}} f(u,v)\,du\,dv=0$ for any two continuous RVs $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445925/jointly-continuous-random-variables?rq=1) related post says that the $P(X=Y)=0$ when $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what sense you mean $X=Y$.

For example, if they're equal pointwise  (i.e. for all elements of the sample space $\omega$, $X(\omega) = Y(\omega)$) or almost surely (pointwise, except on possibly a set of $P$-measure zero), then $P(X=Y)=1$.

However, if they're equal only in distribution, then of course not. Take $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y = -X$. Then, $P(X=Y) = P(X=0) = 0$ but $X=Y$ in distribution.

Comment: What if nothing is mentioned specifically? Does that make it an ambiguous question?

Comment: @StubbornAtom I haven't seen anyone using $X = Y$ to indicate that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. (Although I have seen some abuse of notation such as $X = \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, the RHS is not a random variable and there is little chance of ambiguity.) It is usually denoted by $$X \sim Y, \qquad X \stackrel{d}{=} Y, \qquad X \stackrel{\text{law}}{=} Y, \qquad \cdots $$ That being said, I would safely assume that the equality is intended at least as strong as $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. sense: $\mathbb{P}(X = Y) = 1$.

Comment: If its a homework question, I'd ask for a clarification. But otherwise, I'd agree with @SangchulLee.

Comment: I came up with this question myself motivated by a similar exercise. This is definitely not homework.